# Touchpad only found occasionaly

Tags: touchpad, alps

Only, like every fifth restart is my touchpad found by Ubuntu 11.10. I suspect this might be a hardware failure, but I'm not sure so i throw this question out here. I don't run Windows on this computer so can't check like that.

Anyway, the computer is a Dell Vostro 1310 and the touchpad is an "AlpsPS/2 Alps GlidePoint". If I check the `/proc/bus/input/devices` file the touchpad is only listed those times it works. Otherwise it's not visible in this file. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

To me it certainly sounds like hardware related. 
Maybe some loose wiring?  or maybe your touchpad has a physical button that disables it that you happen to switch?

Comment: If the wiring was loose, I would except it to sometimes stop working when the computer is started. But I can have the computer started for a whole day and the trackpad works all the time. And the same goes for the theory of me accidentally pressing a button... :-/